# Change SVG color depending on the background color behind

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG I used on my page but there is a slight issue.

[image]

As you can see the part on the white area of the background is white and I want it to be green so it can have this effect of color difference.

I tried `mix-blend-mode: difference;` but no use it only gives a mixture between pink and black and I don't want this.

I added an HTML and CSS snippets as a codepen link
https://codepen.io/HuangLinBao/pen/dyvbebO since the code exceeded the character limit

Comment: Could you post your code in a snippet?

Comment: did you try ```mix-blend-mode: multiply;```?

Comment: @DavidGrosh no use it just reduce opacity a bit

Comment: @AliKlein I added the code